# Multi Level JSON Filter

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, filter, momentjs

**So I have this json:**

```
this.state = {
  projects: [{
    id: 10,
    name: "Project 10",
    runTimes: [{
      id: 186,
      name: "Do Homeworks",
      start: "2020-W01",
      end: "2020-W09",
      project: 10,
      users: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Sander Cokart",
        runTime: [
          186
        ]
      }]
    }],
    hidden: false
  }, ]
}
```

And I wish to filter based on runTimes.start & end,

I have already tried this:

```
    const filtered = array.filter((project) => {
        if (!project.hidden) {
            if (project.runTimes.filter((runTime) => {
                if (moment(runTime.start).isSameOrAfter(context.searchFrom) &&
                    moment(runTime.end).isSameOrBefore(context.searchTo)) {
                    return runTime;
                }
            }).length > 0) {
                return project;
            }
        }
    });
```

sadly it doesn't work the second a second RunTime exists inside a project object RunTimes array.

anyone have an idea?

Comment: What is the value of `array` in `array.filter`? Is that the same as `this.state.projects.filter`?

Comment: yes indeed array = this.state.projects

Answer (score 0):

The filter functions are just a bit off. I'd argue the if statement wrapped around the filter is confusing, I'd go for something simpler. This is working for me:

```
const result = array.projects.filter((project) => {
  return !project.hidden && project.runTimes.filter(runTime => {
    return moment(runTime.start).isSameOrAfter("2020-W01") &&
      moment(runTime.end).isSameOrBefore("2020-W12")
  })
});
```

Comment: sadly this doesn't clear out any filtered items from the array whenever the state is updated in react. So while it returns false it doesn't update the array which still holds the same items prior to filter

Comment: So after the last return it needs the following

return moment(runTime.start).isSameOrAfter("2020-W01") &&
      moment(runTime.end).isSameOrBefore("2020-W12")
  }).length > 0;

but even then it only hides when its out of range for the first one in the runtimes array

Comment: have you tried using `Array.prototype.some()` instead of filter with the length check?